# Remove numbering of unreferenced theorems

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems

Can theorems, lemmas, etc., be automatically displayed without numbers if not referenced (like `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}` for equation tags)?

Comment: You might want to refer to a lemma when exposing the contents of the paper; a number can be handy anyway.

Comment: That is true. The question remains though.

Comment: Damn, where is my [tag:please-do-not-do-that] tag when I need it?

Comment: If you know what it looks like, just fake it.  In other words, don't use \begin{theorem}  etc.

Comment: right now I'm using starred environments, but this is not good enough. I'm writing lecture notes, and it is not always clear where to put a star; I think it is helpful to omit numbers as an indication that a particular Example/Lemma/etc has local impact. (It would be even better to have a list of _where_ it is used, if at all).

Comment: It would make much more sense to ask the same question about equations instead...

Comment: @strpeter: it is probably for that reason that that question has been asked and answered more often

Comment: @user66081: I am not sure what you mean by your statement "asked and answered more often"?

Answer (score 9):

This is certainly not the most elegant solution but it works:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\helpercommand}{} 
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{\label{thm#1}\ref{#1}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thm}[1]
{
\renewcommand{\helpercommand}{#1}
\ifcsname r@thm#1\endcsname\begin{theorem}\else\begin{theorem*}\fi\label{#1}
}
{
\ifcsname r@thm\helpercommand\endcsname\end{theorem}\else\end{theorem*}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{labelA}
This theorem is referenced later.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}{labelB}
This is not.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}{labelC}
This is again.
\end{thm}

Theorems \thmref{labelA} and \thmref{labelC} are great!
\end{document}
```

[image: referenced theorems]

Comment: doesn't this produce multiply defined labels if, say, `\thmref{labelA}` is used multiple times?